# Qual melhor maneira de salvar um objeto Grupo que possui listas de Itens?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tenho um cadastro e nele há vários vinculos, por exemplo:

```
public class Grupo {
   public string Nome {get;set;}
   public List<GrupoItemA> ItensA {get;set;}
   public List<GrupoItemB> ItensB {get;set;}
   public List<GrupoItemC> ItensC {get;set;}
}
public class GrupoItemB {
   public Grupo Grupo {get;set;}
   public ItemA Item {get;set;}
   public string Observacao {get;set;}
}
```

Tenho definido minhas classes.

Minha dúvida é, eu quero que o usuário possa ir vinculando todos os Itens na View e apenas quando enviar o POST para salvar que ele salve tudo, ou seja, salva o Grupo e depois as classes de Itens.

Qual seria a melhor maneira para fazer isso?

Pensei em Session, mas me falaram que não é boa prática e pode ficar pesado se houver muitos itens.

Pensei armazenar tudo em Array no Javascript, mas se caso der erro ou algo, ele perderá tudo.

Ou também em alguma classe estática

Como eu poderia obter melhor resultado nesse caso?

Comment: Penso que o ideal seria você usar o JS para escrever no HTML. Se eu tiver mais tempo respondo depois.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Minha dúvida é, eu quero que o usuário possa ir vinculando todos os Itens na View e apenas quando enviar o POST para salvar que ele salve tudo, ou seja, salva o Grupo e depois as classes de Itens. Qual seria a melhor maneira para fazer isso?

Escrevendo HTML na View. Mas não pode ser qualquer HTML.

Para esta resposta, estou supondo que você conhece como usar o [BeginCollectionItem](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BeginCollectionItem/), um pacote NuGet feito para manipular mestre-detalhe. Tem 4 respostas minhas sobre ele:

- [Mestre-detalhe em MVC C# com Razor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8746/mestre-detalhe-em-mvc-c-com-razor/8749#8749)
- [Dúvida em construção de View e Controller com entidade dependente de cardinalidade N](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15804/d%C3%BAvida-em-constru%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-view-e-controller-com-entidade-dependente-de-cardinalida/15809#15809)
- [Editar lista de objetos com POST do form em MVC C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/30451/editar-lista-de-objetos-com-post-do-form-em-mvc-c/30457#30457)
- [Acessando campos do form gerado dinamicamente.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3175/acessando-campos-do-form-gerado-dinamicamente/3221#3221)

Outra coisa é que não é uma boa prática usar `List` porque `List` é um objeto com propriedades limitadas. A forma recomendada pra usar como *Model* é:

```
[DisplayColumn("Nome")]
public class Grupo 
{
    [Key]
    public int GrupoId { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    public ICollection<GrupoItemA> ItensA {get;set;}
    public ICollection<GrupoItemB> ItensB {get;set;}
    public ICollection<GrupoItemC> ItensC {get;set;}
}
```

Se houver mais dúvidas, por favor, me avise que amplio a resposta.

Comment: não conheço ainda o BeginCollectionItem, estou curioso e depois dou uma olhada. Só não entendi por que que você diz "não é uma boa prática usar List". Já usei muitas vezes sem problemas.

Comment: Porque uma `List` não tem vários métodos que `Collection` tem, como por exemplo, métodos que podem ser estendidos e melhorados para a necessidade da aplicação.

Comment: entendi e concordo. Mas dependendo do cenário o List atende muito bem. Suou um pouco forte quando li que não é boa prática usar rs. Então depende do que você precisa. Valeu pelo retorno.

Comment: Que bom que soou, porque é este o recado. O ideal é sempre usar interfaces pra que o modelo seja o mais elástico possível.

Comment: Cigano, obrigado pela resposta(novamente) o problema de usar esse BeginCollection, é que uma das propriedades que eu tenho é uma combobox que contém valores que vem do banco, então ficaria [Combobox] [Valor1] [Valor2], e não sei se não ficaria muito pesada a tela se tiver muito desses campos...

Comment: @Rod Por que ficaria?

Comment: Muitos campos combobox com listagem... Mas essa lib tem suporte a asp.net mvc 5? vi ali em todos os exemplos, apenas asp.net mvc2

Comment: @Rod Tem sim. Não tem problema usar "muitos campos com listagem". Funciona igual.

Answer (score 3):

Você precisa receber os dados do Grupo e dos Itens do grupo quando o usuário der o Post.

Não sei se é a melhor, mas uma alternativa (que já utilizei várias vezes) para isso é você pode criar um *Model* (como ***GrupoViewModel*** por exemplo) que terá propriedades do tipo listas/*arrays* para receber os Ids de cada lista de itens que seu o usuário selecionou para o Grupo, além dos dados do Grupo (com Id, Nome...) e o nome dos itens, etc.

Exemplo do *Model*:

```
public class GrupoViewModel
{           
    private IRepositorioItem _repositorioItem;

    public GrupoViewModel(IRepositorioItem repositorioItem)
    {
        _repositorioItem = repositorioItem;
    }

    public GrupoViewModel():this()
    {
        PreencherListaDeGrupoItemA();
        PreencherListaDeGrupoItemB();
        PreencherListaDeGrupoItemC();
    }

    //Dados do Grupo
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    //Outros campos do seu model.....

    //Lista de Itens
    public int[] IdsGrupoItemA { get; set; }
    public int[] IdsGrupoItemB { get; set; }
    public int[] IdsGrupoItemC { get; set; }

    private void PreencherListaDeGrupoItemA()
    {
        //Código para buscar e preencher os itens IdsGrupoItemA 
        foreach(var item in _repositorioItem.ObterTodosGrupoItemA())
        {
           //Preenche os dados desejados como IdsGrupoItemA do item, etc...
        }
    }

    private void PreencherListaDeGrupoItemB()
    {
        //Código para buscar e preencher os itens IdsGrupoItemB 
        foreach(var item in _repositorioItem.ObterTodosGrupoItemB())
        {
           //Preenche os dados desejados como IdsGrupoItemB do item, etc...
        }
    }

    private void PreencherListaDeGrupoItemC()
    {
        //Código para buscar e preencher os itens IdsGrupoItemC 
        foreach(var item in _repositorioItem.ObterTodosGrupoItemC())
        {
           //Preenche os dados desejados como IdsGrupoItemC do item, etc...
        }
    }
}
```

No *Controller*, em sua *Action* de ***Get***, você cria uma instância de *GrupoViewModel* preenchendo as informações a serem apresentadas (dados do Grupo e listas de itens).

Para montar sua ***View*** (do tipo *GrupoViewModel*) utilize os Ids dos itens, que já estarão devidamente preenchidos, usando *checkbox* (o que normalmente uso) com o mesmo nome das propriedades para o usuário selecionar os itens desejados.

No *Controller*, em sua *Action* ***Post***, você recebe os Ids dos itens selecionados pelo usuário, para cada Id você recupera o objeto (seja ele GrupoItemA, GrupoItemB e/ou GrupoItemC) e associa/adiciona na lista de item do seu Grupo.

Exemplo *Controller*:

```
public class GrupoController
{
    public ActionResult Create()
    {                    
       return View(new GrupoViewModel());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(GrupoViewModel grupoViewModel)
    {
        ...
        List<GrupoItemA> listaItensAselecionados = new List<GrupoItemA>();
        foreach(var idGrupoItemA in grupoViewModel.IdsGrupoItemA)
        {
            //Recupero o objeto GrupoItemA desse Id e adiciono na lista listaItensAselecionados 
        }

        List<GrupoItemB> listaItensBselecionados = new List<GrupoItemB>();
        foreach(var idGrupoItemB in grupoViewModel.IdsGrupoItemB)
        {
            //Recupero o objeto GrupoItemB desse Id e adiciono na lista listaItensBselecionados 
        }

        List<GrupoItemC> listaItensCselecionados = new List<GrupoItemC>();
        foreach(var idGrupoItemC in grupoViewModel.IdsGrupoItemC)
        {
            //Recupero o objeto GrupoItemC desse Id e adiciono na lista listaItensCselecionados 
        }

        ...

        //Agora com os itens selecionados recuperados você cria o Grupo novo
    }
}
```

Comment: Olá Renan, entendi sua resposta, mas acho que estou com mais dificuldade de preenche-las nas view, assim como você, eu também utilizo checkbox, mas, ao clicar no checkbox eu abro uma modal para inserir outras informações adicionais...aí eu to tentando deixar uma Session do tpo GrupoViewModel, assim como você mostrou...e indo adicionando via ajax os dados..aí salvo, gravo tudo e destruo a sessão

Comment: @Rod entendi, mas aí recomendo você abrir uma pergunta específica sobre a situação dessa modal (que não estava na pergunta rs) para tentarmos ajudá-lo (você poderia até colocar o link dessa pergunta como referência). As respostas aqui focam sua dúvida inicial sobre como salvar um objeto Grupo que possui listas de Itens.

Answer (score 1):

Duas boas estratégias seriam usar (1) objetos leves (lightweight objects) e/ou (2) caches.

1. Objetos leves são objetos preenchidos apenas com os campos de identificação e de exibição para o usuário, por exemplo "id" e "descricao".
2. Cache é uma forma de armazenamento temporário da informação e de acesso rápido. Para .Net você pode ler sobre cache aqui: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997357%28v=VS.100%29.aspx